# Getting 404 error when fetching service-worker on next.js + firebase hosting pwa app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

Getting 404 error when fetching service-worker on next.js + firebase hosting pwa app
I am trying to make PWA application by adding service-worker to this next.js + firebase hosting application introduced in this repository.
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting

However, although it runs up to hosting, I am having trouble running service-worker.js.

I think that the cause is path to service-worker.js file, which is in dist/functions/next folder. So I tried change pass, but I cannot solve it.

```
Service worker registration failed, error1:  TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

Is there any idea to solve this probrem?
below is the functions/index.js file.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const next = require('next');
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const { join } = require('path');
const { parse } = require('url');
const express = require('express');

const routes = require('./routes');

// Region hosting next.js to cloud function

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev, conf: { distDir: 'next' } });
const handle = routes.getRequestHandler(app);

const server = express();
server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));
server.get('/service-worker', (req, res) => {
  // try change pass but not worked
  // app.serveStatic(req, res, '_next/service-worker.js'),
  // app.serveStatic(req, res, 'next/service-worker.js');
  // app.serveStatic(req, res, '/service-worker.js');
  // app.serveStatic(req, res, '/next/service-worker.js');

  const filePath = join(__dirname , 'service-worker.js')
  app.serveStatic(req, res, filePath);
});

exports.next = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log('File: ' + req.originalUrl); // log the page.js file that is being requested

  return app.prepare().then(() => {
    server(req, res);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/hanford/next-offline seems to be the recommended approach to PWAs with next.js. You need to instruct workbox to put the generated service-worker.js in the public directory when your app is built.

Here's an example next.config.js:

```
const withOffline = require('next-offline')
const config = {
  workboxOpts: {
    swDest: '../public/service-worker.js',
  },
    // rest of your config
}
module.exports = withOffline(config)
```

Comment: I get this error `Error: Source and destination must not be the same.` from the `fs-extra` lib on nextjs 9.4 when running `next export` if I set `swDest` to a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.
The reason why I fail is the order of server.get method, which means that firstly I should write server.get('/service-worker') then servet.get(*).
And, change file path from join(__dirname , 'service-worker.js') to  'next/service-worker.js')